# Using the default Wordpress permalink structure on custom post types

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a clean permalink structure for my website. Something like this  `www.website.com/blog/topic`

But I have a plugin that produces pages under the category "matches".
`www.website.com/matches/him_vs_her`

And for some reason the plugin doesn't seem to work with that /%postname%/ permalink structure. It only works with the default structure.

```
www.website.com/?p=234=matches
```

If i use any permalink structure besides the default, I get a 404 error. How can i use this default permalink structure with only that post type? So that it doesn't affect SEO for my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: /%category%/%postname%/ , and make sure your links are updated to reflect this change. A quick solve to many 404's after changes to permalink is a simple permalink refresh.. which consists of simply going to settings->permalinks and clicking save again. (without any changes)